# What type of wire should be used for 230 v ac while using this relay

Tags: ac, relay, soldering, wire

I want to drive a 230v bulb with the help of a relay, so I soldered a 5v relay on a perforated board with a transistor driver circuit which is working perfectly fine. The relay I am using is HL JQC-3FC(T73) whose datasheet is [here](http://www.langirele.com/pdf/pcb-relay-T73.pdf)

But I would like to know what type of wire should I use for 230v ac appliances(Single strand or multistrand, the thickness etc).

Also I know that I cannot use two rails(for rails I mean the lead lines which I use to connect electronics components on my soldering board) which are side by side on the board which carry 230v ac voltages, so what should be the distances of such rails.

Thankyou for your time

Comment: What current does your load require? Or, to put it another way, what is the wattage of the appliance in question?

Comment: Thankyou for the response.....Well lets take it the maximum which my relay can  provide... Is it fine? @uint128_t. Also you can take a 100W incandescent bulb .

Comment: Please tell me you're not bringing 230V onto the perfboard...

Comment: No I didnt but I used wires which could sustain 230 volts  to make connections to the relay @BrianDrummond and these wires had to be soldered to the relay pins on the perf board... What would happen if did??

Comment: I would remove any copper on the perfboard within 7mm of those pins. Sounds like that's what you've done.

Comment: Well yes that's what I did.. @BrianDrummond Any other things to consider or any other suggestions? These might help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type if wire is depended on the use of the wire. If you move it the wire has to be flexible -> multistrand.
The thickness is depended on the current. 1.5mm² is good for 16A.

Comment: I am looking for explanation. I know normally multistrand wires are used and I also got the result with it but I would like to know technically which should be used and why.

Comment: The thickness of the wire is depended of the current because the wire has a resistant as well. You will not heat up your wire because is some thermal insulation around it it could got too hot melt the insulation or catch fire. The second issue is that if the wire resistant is in a noticeable range to the load you get a voltag drop along the wire.

Comment: Mmhmm thats a good point ... That should be included in the answer .. and  Thats it? dont we have any other considerations?... Beside it what about the rails on the board? Should I consider the thickness of lead tracks here too on the soldering board...What should be the distance between these rails?

Comment: For the distance between the 230V and the 5V  there are requirements. I don't know where you located. In Germany you will find it in the VDE specification. Your relay has an distance of 9mm between the coil connector and the contact connector. This seems a good distance.

Comment: For the tracks on the soldering board you have to design it according to the current which goes through. If you have a 0.1mm line width and 16A the line will blow away.

Comment: OK since you said that the distances of relay pins are good i.e., they are safe so considering it as a reference I would set the distances of 230v power rails and 5v rails that way.... and I found that between a 230v rail and 5v rails.. it is approximately no more than 7mm... Thankyou for the tip... but it would be much better if we found a minimum distance but nevertheless it would do the job!

Comment: The point is that you can calculate the minimum distance for a spark in air. Than you have to consider pollution, not flat surface, humidity, air pressure etc. Than you add a margin to be sure and this is what you find in the regulation.